# Crash report, bug and task management automation

Tags: automation, logs, debugging, issue-tracker, task-management

I need to collect logs from users, automatically merge them and track how many different users have the same bug.

I don't even know good keywords for such programs.

I believe it should be BugSplat or something like that: https://www.bugsplat.com/blog/product/crash-grouping-and-aggregation

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community useless trash bot.